# What are the words censored in this interview?

Tags: words

Interview: https://dengekionline.com/elem/000/000/623/623506/index-3.html

In this interview the following passage has series of censored words. After some searching I couldn't figure out what they were. Can anyone help?

ヨコオ：いや、まったく。僕の中で、あれはホストと、ホストに狂ってるオ●●って感覚ですし。

松下：ちょっと！　その表現!!

ヨコオ：●●ギはダメ？　じゃあ、ピ●●でもいいです。

松下：そういう意味じゃないから。何この残念な感じ。

ヨコオ：つまりは、おばさん。ごめんなさい、ホストと●●ン●だな。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://toro.5ch.net/test/read.cgi/gamerpg/1373034324/59-84), オ●●/●●ギ and ピ●● are probably [おすぎ and ピーコ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%81%A8%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B3), respectively, who are twin brothers who have been nationally-known as being オカマ/おネエ since the 70's. I suppose ●●ン● is also a concrete name of someone, but I have no idea who it is.

Comment: It could possibly mean オカマ, オスギ, ピーコ, and トランス(ジェンダー). Since it's said that アンヘル is more like a woman, but as of DOD1, dragons have no gender (they are monosexual and have no sex).